# Error al implementar SDWebImageSwiftUI en Swiftui

Tags: swift, imagen, xcode

Estoy intentando mostrar imagenes gif SDWebImageSwiftUI

> https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI

pero me da error en animated Image url

> Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(url: URL?,
>
> options: SDWebImageOptions)'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier '$isAnimating'

```
import SwiftUI
    import SDWebImageSwiftUI
    import SDWebImage

struct gifView: View {
    var body: some View {
     Group {
            // Network
            AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyong03/YLGIFImage/master/YLGIFImageDemo/YLGIFImageDemo/joy.gif"), options: [.progressiveLoad]) // Progressive Load
            .onFailure { error in
                // Error
            }
            .resizable() // Actually this is not needed unlike SwiftUI.Image
            .placeholder(UIImage(systemName: "photo")) // Placeholder Image
            .indicator(SDWebImageActivityIndicator.medium) // Activity Indicator
            .transition(.fade) // Fade Transition
            .scaledToFit() // Attention to call it on AnimatedImage, but not `some View` after View Modifier

            // Data
            AnimatedImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/foo.webp")))
            .customLoopCount(1) // Custom loop count
            .playbackRate(2.0) // Playback speed rate

            // Bundle (not Asset Catalog)
        AnimatedImage(name: "animation1", isAnimating: $isAnimating);) // Animation control binding
            .maxBufferSize(.max)
            .onViewUpdate { view, context in // Advanced native view coordinate
                view.toolTip = "Mouseover Tip"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct gifView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        gifView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//
//  gifView.swift
//  umbre
//
//  Created by Desarollo on 11/27/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Dream. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import SDWebImage

struct gifView: View {
      let url = URL(string: "https://s5.gifyu.com/images/ubrellagif.gif")!
     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             AnimatedImage(url: url)
                 .scaledToFit()
                 .frame(width: 850, height: 850)

         }
     }
}

struct gifView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        gifView()
    }
}
```